# Parse a URL and remove end portion

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to parse URLs.  For example where I am trying to pull out:

```
~/locations/1 => [locations,1]
~/locations/1/comments => [locations,1]
~/locations/1/comments/22 => [locations,1]
~/locations/1/buildings/3 => [buildings,3]
~/locations/1/buildings/3/comments => [buildings,3]
~/locations/1/buildings/3/comments/34 => [buildings,3]
```

The format is pretty consistent.  I started with arrays but it seems to still fail:

```
@request_path = request.path.downcase.split('/')
@comment_index = @request_path.index("comments").to_i
if @comment_index > 0
  @request_path = @request_path.drop_while { |i| i.to_i >= @comment_index }
end
resource, id = @request_path.last(2)
```

I added the downcase just incase someone manually typed in an uppercase URL.  The drop_while seems to not be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of output you have after processing your code?

## Edited

Your problem is that you convert element `to_i` and it is `0`. But you want to compare `index` of element, but can normally get `index` of element in that situation using [Array#index](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-index) method.

**Correct approach:**

```
@request_path.drop_while { |i| @request_path.index(i) >= @comment_index }
```

You can parse `path` without `drop_while`.

**My solution:**

```
def resource_details(path)
    resource_array = path.downcase.split("/").reject!(&:empty?)
    key = resource_array.index("comments")
    return key.present? ? (resource_array - resource_array[key..key + 1]).last(2) : resource_array.last(2)
 end
```

It will cut out `["comments"]` or `["comments","2"]` for your path.

Invoke that method:

```
1.9.3p0 :051 > resource_details("/locations/1/buildings/3/comments")
 => ["buildings", "3"] 

1.9.3p0 :052 > resource_details("/locations/1/comments/2")
 => ["locations", "1"]
```

Comment: My code works except that it doesn't seem to drop the comments out. I want the underlining resource that is NOT the comments. The comment are polymorphic and I am trying to parse the resource and id of a given path regardless of the presence of comments.